# MAgento 2 Not Visible Individually creates a 404 error

Tags: magento, magento2

with Magento 2.3.5-p2 if I set a product (grouped product) as NOT VISIBILE INDIVIDUALLY I have a 404 error if i go through url.

I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour. The config is meant to make the product you mark as "not visible individually", well, not visible individually.

Usually you would use this feature to hide the individual products of bundle or configurable products and only show the grouped product to your customer, meaning:

- product a -> NOT VISIBLE INDIVIDUALLY
- product b -> NOT VISIBLE INDIVIDUALLY
- product ab -> VISIBLE INDIVIDUALLY

would only show product ab to your customer, but not it's components a and b.